# removing space using PHP

Tags: php, expression, space

Please help! I have the pricelist in CSV format. Prices are shown like 1 space 325. Instead of 1325. So the script takes only first argument of that price. How can I pass whole price. Here is what I am intending to use:

```
$strua='UAH';
    if(strpos($variant['price'],$str) !== false){
    //removing space sign
    }
```

Comment: Please post a bigger code example, this would make it easyser to help you.

Comment: Have a look at [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: try this $string = preg_replace('/\s/', '', $original_string);

Comment: use trim function http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp

Comment: Could also match `/[^\d]/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
$strua='1 325';
$strua = str_replace(' ', '', $strua);
```

Also read more about [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

to remove spaces:

```
$str = str_replace(" ","",$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace()` with `trim()`:

```
$string = '1 325';
$string = str_replace(' ', '', trim($str));
```

Documentation: [**`str_replace()`**](http://php.net/str_replace), [**`trim()`**](http://php.net/trim)

Comment: Why should he use trim?

Answer (score 0):

**Remove Whitespace:**

```
$ro = preg_replace('/\s/', '',$str]);
```

**Example:**

```
<?php
$str ="1 325";
$ro = preg_replace('/\s/', '',$str);
echo $ro;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
1325
```

**Note:**

```
\s => Single Whitespace
\s+ =>  Excess whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

Here what solved the problem.

```
$strua='грн';
    if(strpos($variant['price'],$strua) !== false){

  $variant_price = str_replace(' ', '', $variant['price']);
  $variant['price']=$variant_price;
        }
```